# How does Nginx act as both reverse proxy and web server?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, web-server, reverse-proxy

This might be a naive question. But I'm too new to client and server concept and wanted to know.

I understood what a **Reverse proxy** is - a server that sits in between clients and origin servers and forwards requests on behalf of clients to actual servers.

I understood what a **web server** is - a server that actually serves the `http` content.

What I don't understand is - **Nginx** act as both **Reverse proxy** and **Web server**. How does it act as both when both are different.

Comment: This is probably not the right place for this question. But maybe it helps you if I tell you that nginx doesn't forward blindly, but it interprets the http request and sends its own request to the backend.

Comment: When deploying a django app, I didn't use any server other than nginx which is `reverse-proxy` as per your statement. Where is it forwarding the requests to? I didn't configure any other servers. Am I looking at it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically **Nginx** administers a domain's (e.g. `example.com`) webspace, i.e. all `URL`s starting with `http://example.com` or `https://example.com`. It can serve all those `URL`s in any way he wishes (or rather according to its configuration), e.g. it can:

- fetch the content for `URL`s starting with `http://example.com/app` from another server. This way it acts as a reverse proxy,
- serve the content for the remaining `URL`s himself.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link 
this will help you out

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/